# Не получается подключить js файл через CDN

Tags: javascript, cdn

Впервые подключаю js через cdn, не пойму в чём проблема?! Просьба без токсичных комментариев.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script async language="javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tictic@0.1.0/cjs/lib/getDate.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(getDate({}))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что это за скрипт? Если это результат сборки - как именно происходит сборка?

Comment: Ts компилятором

Comment: tsc сделал вам CommonJS, но браузеры не умеют CommonJS.

Comment: Ок, но скрипт из каталога esm тоже не работает

Comment: Может нужно другим сборщиком собирать?

Comment: Может надо importHelpers убрать?

Comment: Добавь исходный код `getDate` до сборки и `tsconfig`

Comment: @teplostanski, проблема не в сборщике а в настройках

Comment: https://github.com/teplostanski/tictic/blob/main/src/lib/getDate.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл собран в виде модуля CommonJS - этот формат модулей не поддерживается в браузере.

Поэтому в текущем виде код не сможет заработать.

Нужно либо подключать в виде обычного js, либо в виде модуля `ECMAModule` - в этом случае к тегу `<script>` необходимо будет добавить атрибут `type="module"`.

В `tsconfig` установлено свойство [`importHelpers`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#importHelpers)

```
"importHelpers": true,
```

Данное свойство позволяет не дублировать хелперы добавляемые компилятором во время сборки, а подключать их из отдельного модуля. Однако данного модуля нет для браузеров.

Для решения достаточно выставить значение `false`, в этом случае хелперы добавятся в сам файл.

Также можно убрать атрибут `async` у подключаемого скрипта

```html
<script type="module">
  import {getDate} from 'https://unpkg.com/tictic@0.1.1/esm/lib/getDate.js'; 

  console.log(getDate);
</script>
```

Comment: Есть там ESM в соседней папке.

Comment: А ещё неплохо бы убрать `async` из поключения

Comment: ```<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script async type="module" language="javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tictic@0.1.0/esm/lib/getDate.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(getDate({}))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ругается на tslib

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tslib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а, ejs пробовал :) поэтому не нашел

Comment: НУ я просто на https://unpkg.com/browse/tictic@0.1.0/ зашёл. Исходники, кстати, вот https://github.com/teplostanski/tictic/

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ага, я похоже что-то лишнее убирал пока пробовал - поэтому не нашлось сразу

Comment: Я поправил сборку https://unpkg.com/tictic@0.1.1/esm/lib/getDate.js. но всё равно туплю, в консоль сыпится ошибка getDate is not defined @Grundy

Comment: Затупил, нужно было так <script type="module" language="javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tictic@0.1.1/esm/lib/getDate.js">
  let d = getDate({})
console.log(d)
</script> а я в разных скриптах это делал, я думал так и нужно, в одном скрипте подключаешь, а в другом используешь?!

Comment: @teplostanski, в разных и надо

Comment: Но у меня не получилось

Comment: @Grundy, если в разных, то getDate is not defined . Сборщиков никаких нет, голый html

Comment: @teplostanski в принципе первый script не нужен в импорте можно сразу указывать урл

Comment: @Grundy с урлом в импорте работает, но хотелось бы разобраться почему не работает с первым скриптом, что я делаю не так, вдруг в жизни пригодится

Answer (score -1):

Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию getDate в вашем скрипте, но она не определена в вашем коде и не импортирована из подключенного вами скрипта. Для использования этой функции вам нужно сначала убедиться, что она доступна, либо импортировать ее из подключенного модуля.